# React Native - Integrating Ace-Editor with React Native Application

Tags: react-native, ace-editor

Is there any way to integrate the Ace Editor into a React Native Application (how)? I'm quite new to React and switched from Swift. Or is there a Code Editor that can be implemented into react native already?

Answer (score 0):

You can install this package to integrate code editor into react native where you can add JavaScript code and execute it.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-monacco-editor

**Step - 1:**

Install the package:

```
npm i react-native-monacco-editor
```

**Step -2:**

```
import CodeEditor from 'react-native-monacco-editor';
```

Now you are good to go. You can play with JavaScript code in your mobile with react native.

Answer (score -1):

While developing a React Native application in an **emulator** you will see Red Box with stack trace in it for errors. If your "**REACT_EDITOR**" variable and **path** is set properly then by clicking in the stack trace will take you to the **source file in the editor where the error(s)/warning(s) occurred**.

I have configured my windows 10 machine like this for WebStorm.
My WebStorm file is located here: "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\WebStorm 2018.1.2\bin\webstorm64.exe"

so i add this "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\WebStorm 2018.1.2\bin\" as a path variable for user.

And then put webstorm64.exe as the value of "REACT_EDITOR"

For Ubuntu you can set "REACT_EDITOR" pointing to an editor of your choice like these. open .profile file from terminal like this

```
sudo gedit $HOME/.profile
```

then add this line at the end

> export REACT_EDITOR=/opt/WebStorm-181.4668.60/bin/webstorm.sh

then this command `source $HOME/.profile` to save changes, and restart your pc.
[image: Connecting Websotrm with Emulator in Windows for React-native development]
[image: Connecting Websotrm with Emulator in Ubuntu for React-native development]

Comment: Think you misunderstood the context of the qn: was asking how to integrate ace.js into the app, not the editor editing the code for the app. Thanks anyways